# Passing array of integers to an ApiController in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a simple api-controller in a ASP.NET Core 2.1 like this:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SumController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("CalculateSum")]
    public int CalculateSum(int a, int b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    [HttpGet("CalculateSumOfArray")]
    public int CalculateSumOfArray(int[] values)
    {
        return values.Sum();
    }
}
```

The first method works with a call like this:

```
https://localhost:44346/api/Sum/CalculateSum?a=1&b=2
```

But the second:

```
https://localhost:44346/api/Sum/CalculateSumOfArray?values=1&values=2&values=3
```

just responds with:

```
{"":["The input was not valid."]}.
```

Do I need to do something special to make it possible to send an array to an ApiController?

Answer (score 0):

Add the **FromQuery** attribute like this:

```
    [HttpGet("CalculateSumOfArray")]
    public int CalculateSumOfArray([FromQuery(Name = "values")] int[] values)
    {
        return values.Sum();
    }
```